# Error retrieving cursor value as string

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-database

I have an SQLite-Database with four columns

1. ID
2. Name
3. symptoms
4. Medicine

My Helper class code

```
        public Cursor getMedicine(String symptom1)
        {

            SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c =  db.rawQuery("SELECT medicine FROM diseases WHERE symptoms = ?;",new String[] {symptom1});
            c.moveToFirst();
            return c;
        }
```

And here is code of my activity class :

```
    String med = "";

    Disp_med_DBHelper medicalHelp = new Disp_med_DBHelper(this);
    medicalHelp.open();
    medicalHelp.getMedicine(Value1);
    med = medicalHelp.getMedicine(Value1).toString();

    t1.setText(med);
    medicalHelp.close();
```

Where t1 is my textbox, and Value1 is the string that we need to send to database helper to query the database.

When I check output on my textbox, I get the following output

```
    android.database.sqlire.SQLiteCursor@4174986
```

What should I do to get it fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method toString() returns string representation of object Cursor. You have to use method getString(int column) from Cursor class.

Something like this:
med = medicalHelp.getMedicine(Value1).getString(0);

More info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Answer (score 1):

use this method instead:

```
  public String getMedicine(String symptom1) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT medicine FROM diseases WHERE symptoms = ?;", new String[]{symptom1});
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("medicine"));
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then in your activity:

```
med = medicalHelp.getMedicine(Value1)
if(med!=null){
   t1.setText(med);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even when the cursor contains only a single value, it still behaves as a cursor that might have multiple columns and multiple rows. So you have to go to the first row (with `moveToFirst()`, which might fail), and read the value from the first column (with `getString(0)`).

However, for this simple situation, there is a [helper function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#stringForQuery%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) that allows you to avoid having to muck around with a cursor:

```java
    public Cursor getMedicine(String symptom1) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        return DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(db,
                    "SELECT medicine FROM diseases WHERE symptoms = ?;",
                    new String[]{ symptom1 });
    }
```